# parse4cn1 has some issue when working with Node JS and parse-server open source

Tags: json, node.js, codenameone, parse4cn1

The **parse4cn1** library works well with **parse.com** but it has some issues when working with **Node 4.3.2** and **parse-server open source**. For example, when calling the **ParseUser.signup()** function, the ***"Invalid key name"*** exception is always happened. I tried to debug and figure out that the **ParseCommand** object should add the **ParseConstants.CONTENT_TYPE_JSON** to its header in order to make it can work. I don't why because it still works without doing this with **parse.com**.

Another issue is the **ParseQuery.find()** is always failed when using the **ParseQuery.whereContainedIn()**. The server exception is ***"ParseException [code=102, msg=Improper encode of parameter, cause=null]"***. I guess this issue probably regarding the parameter has the **json format** in this case as well but I don't know to to resolve it. Any advice is appreciate. [Sidiabale](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1291040/sidiabale), do you have any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please create issues in github for these problems? For the second one, please provide as much details as you can  (e.g. the full query that's going wrong and if possible, a ParseServer sandbox where I can do some testing because I've not yet gotten around setting up one myself). Cheers

Comment: I followed this [link](https://medium.com/@cristi_ursachi/installing-your-own-parse-server-on-windows-b2c7a2498d19#.o6whf51we) to install PARSE environment on Windows. I think the PARSE open source modules have not been stable yet. So I decided to create my own database and web services which will be deployed on cloud for production.

Answer (score 0):

These problems are solved in [version 3.0](https://github.com/sidiabale/parse4cn1/releases/tag/parse4cn1-3.0) of `parse4cn1`. Apparently, Parse Server is stricter with the need to specify the content-type header so code that previously worked with Parse.com does not work with Parse Server. I've addressed these issues in the aforementioned release. Try again with version 3.0 and let me know if you encounter any issues.