# What will happen to parse4cn1 when they shut down parse.com?

Tags: codenameone, parse4cn1

As some of us have noted, parse.com will be shut down in January 2017. In the current version of parse4cn1, all requests go to https://api.parse.com, using the constant `ParseConstants.API_ENDPOINT`. Will it be possible to supply a custom URL here, pointing to a different Parse Server? If not, can I build parse4cn1 from source myself? Or should I be looking for an alternative to Parse?

Comment: I've released an update of parse4cn1 that addresses the parse4cn1 part of your question. See: https://github.com/sidiabale/parse4cn1/releases/tag/parse4cn1-3.0 Let me know if you encounter any problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See these related questions:

- [Will Parse4cn1 still work after Parse server retirement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35984381/will-parse4cn1-still-work-after-parse-server-retirement)
- [parse4cn1 has some issue when working with Node JS and parse-server open source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36113903/parse4cn1-has-some-issue-when-working-with-node-js-and-parse-server-open-source)

I now have some time available and intend to make the change you proposed within the coming month or so and make a release that is compatible with the open source Parse server. If that's too late for you, consider making the changes yourself and contributing back via a Github pull request. The [Contributing](https://github.com/sidiabale/parse4cn1#contributing) section of the `parse4cn1` repo provides useful tips.

Regarding looking at Parse alternatives, that's a decision you'll have to make yourself based on your needs and timeline. My gut feeling is that the Open Source Parse Server will mature and grow in features in the months leading up to the official retirement of Parse.com.